# Deformation in topology

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Can we deform a curvy 2-manifold (surface embedded in 3D) so that the resulting homeomorphic surface consists of flat faces only. Like taking a sphere and deforming it to a cube. If that's true, is there a way of knowing when the resulting shape is going to be convex or non-convex?

Comment: Convex shapes can be homeomorphic to non-convex ones (imagine denting a cube), so I'm not sure your second question necessarily makes sense.

Comment: This might be close to what you're looking for: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_%28topology%29

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is what you're after, but the torus is homeomorphic to this:

[image]

(*not a perfect representation, but you get the idea*)

and you can do the same thing for any closed orientable surface - basically, just [add more holes and more pieces as needed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface#Classification_of_closed_surfaces).

Comment: Is that shape like a big rectangle with the middle cube removed?

Comment: @saadtaame Yes.